# Telerik Kendo UI Window

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

I have a view which displays a list of items (as below).  I would like to use the KendoUI window as a popup editor, which would appear after the user clicks on a button or link. I already have a partial view which would be the content of the button. So if I could somehow inject this in.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <div></div>
      <input type="button" id="btnReject" value="Edit" onclick="ConfirmReject(item.id);"       />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate event attached to the table with filter set to 'tr' element (more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). And open the window [programatically by specifying its content](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/api.html). To create the content easily you can [templates](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview).